# NSOutlineViewDelegate in High Sierra not working

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoa

I am a novice learning Swift and xcode by rewriting a code I originally developed in Javascript/PHP/MySql. I am working in macOS, using a storyboard in xcode as my basis for development.  At the moment I am developing a SplitView.  In the Master side I have an OutlineView.  It has three levels, the outer two are expandable, and, until today, it worked just fine. All levels were populated, visible, and expandable where appropriate. I had Swift(4.0) and xcode (9.1) up-to-date as far as I know. So, today I decided it was time to update from Sierra to High Sierra. My master view has now gone completely blank.  Nada.  I tried to track the problem down and discovered, using the debugger in xcode, that the outlineView function in the NSOutlineViewDelegate extension to my MasterViewController is, apparently, not being called at all! I checked the Connections Inspector, and the connections to DataSource and Delegate are still intact.  I searched online and found a few people with what seemed to be vaguely related recent problems associated with Cocoa bindings, but I could not connect their problem solution to mine since I am not using Cocoa bindings...it's on my list, but I am not there yet.  The only thing I know that changed was going from Sierra to High Sierra.   Any suggestions?  Thanks!

ADDED:  I now know a bit more about the problem.

Here is the code that works prior to High Sierra:

class ViewController: NSViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var webView: WebView!

@IBOutlet weak var outlineView: NSOutlineView!

var feeds = Feed

let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()

override func viewDidLoad() {

```
super.viewDidLoad()

dateFormatter.dateStyle = .short

if let filePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Feeds", ofType: "plist") {
  feeds = Feed.feedList(filePath)
  print(feeds)
}
```

}

The code is taken from a tutorial on the OutlineView on the Ray_Wenderlich.com site. I patterned my code after this and both the tutorial and my code worked...until High Sierra.  Apparently, until High Sierra, the system would spontaneously parse "feeds" and generate the outlineView display.  With High Sierra the behavior changed and it no longer spontaneously produced the outlineView, neither in the tutorial nor my project. The result was a blank outLineView.

In a comment added to the tutorial, I now find that someone else had encountered the same behavior and suggested that the code now needed:

outlineView.reloadData(),

but my naive implementation of that suggestion simply generated a runtime error,

"[NSView reloadData]: unrecognized selector sent to instance"

Comment: Please format your questions, it looks hard to read

Comment: Show your work.  'not working' doesn't work for anyone but you unless you want help for your English composition class.

Comment: agree with @ElTomato

Comment: This is the code that was working prior to the upgrade to High Sierra.

Comment: Sorry, still trying to figure out how this site works.  I'll try again.

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure that when you start a new ‘Playground’ you have macOS as an application checked and not IOS. If you have IOS checked Swift will import UIKit (instead of Cocoa) which will cause your problem. GL.